# I've lost 5 units of reputation. How I can find out why?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I've lost 5 units of reputation. How I can find out why?

Comment: I do not like it when someone asks a question hiding the fact that he/she had asked the same question somewhere before (and even had received an answer).  http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/141048#141048

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reputation points wild fluctuations?](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/534/reputation-points-wild-fluctuations)

Comment: Oops, I think that I miscalculated the time difference.  It seems that Walter Bishop’s answer was posted in chat after you posted this question here.  My apologies for incorrectly accusing you for hiding the fact that you had received an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's been lots of discussion on this. Losing 5 points in one shot is probably a reversal of a question upvote, and the problem is that such reversals merely erase the previous upvote, so you can't track it. One thing you can do though is look at cstheory.stackexchange.com/reputation once you're logged in. It gives you the entire history of points.

Comment: Does cstheory.stackexchange.com/reputation show canceled votes?

Comment: no, but if you monitor it obsessively you can get a diff :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone canceled an upvote for one of your questions.  If this is the case, I do not know any way to verify it unless you had recorded the number of votes for your questions before you lost 5 rep points.

Comment: There are periodic recalcs.  Maybe someone made a question community wiki, maybe someone voted for all his questions too fast so the "suspicious voting pattern" script was enabled. I've lost maybe 100 points in a recalc before.  It's just part of the reality of the site I think.